# Use wait command as a function

Tags: bash, shell, wait

I'd like to create a function that will wait until a command is completed before moving on to the next line(s).
I'm aware of the wait built in command, but I believe it only works for child processes.
Im looking something like below and I'm not exactly sure on how to construct the working code or logic. Any help would be helpful.

```
wait_pid () {
 pid=$1
 wait $pid
 echo "Exit status: $?"
 if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then exit 1; fi
}

wait_pid kubectl rollout undo deployment/app --to-revision=2
```

and fails if the command is unsuccessful and moves on if the command is successful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to a function `wait-for-something-to-end`:

In a script, when you do something like this:

```
action_1
action_2
...
```

Then, `action_2` will only start when `action_1` is finished.

So, in your case, you can simply do:

```
kubectl rollout undo deployment/app --to-revision=2
do_something_else
```

The `do_something_else` is only started when the other command is finished.

In case that command gives the focus back immediately and continues in some child process, you should look for a parameter to prevent this.

Comment: Reason Im looking for a wait function is that, certain kubectl and other customized commands runs in child process, while the main scripts proceeds to the next lines.

Comment: @voltas: as mentioned in my answer, you should look for a parameter of the `kubectl (rollout)` command, which turns this command in an interactive one (not just launching a child process and giving the focus back, but actually waiting for that child process to be finished). Does that command have a manfile or some help?